# Diagrams in MathJax via xypic.js

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, mathjax

Apparently, [the Stacks project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W7) can load a MathJax extension called `xypic.js` (check the source code) and then has access to `\xymatrix` in their [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org)-$\LaTeX$ code. Would it be possible to add this to MO? Diagrams are always quite difficult to do when you can only use matrix environments.

Comment: You might be interested in the comments to [this discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9401/622) and in [that discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2324/622). (As a footnote, Davide Cervone is one of the developers of MathJax).

Comment: When I checked (which was a while ago) there were still some major unresolved issues. I pinged MathJax developers for their input on the stability and security of `xypic.js`.

Comment: I marked the request as [meta-tag:status-declined] but we can revisit the issue if the XyJax developers offer a support plan which is suitable for our needs.

Comment: @François, you can also use [meta-tag:status-deferred].

Comment: I've retagged as deferred. Clearly this is something we'd like to be able to do, but `xypic.js` may not be ready for prime-time yet.

Comment: I reverted to [meta-tag:status-declined] since there is no plan to implement this. The XyJax developers are, as far as we can tell, nowhere near providing the support we need to deploy on MathOverflow. Of course, we would be happy to revise this if the XyJax developers come up with a suitable support plan.

Comment: To add a bit of context, a while back the main MathJax library had a quite severe security hole, which fortunately was fixed before anyone exploited it. That history makes us pretty wary of XyJax, particularly because no one has had any useful communication with the developer.

Comment: @ScottMorrison: Alright, that actually does explain the wariness. It's still a shame, diagram support would be very much appreciated I think.

Comment: To add to what Scott said, the reason we have to be more wary than the Stacks project is that random people on the internet can immediately post on MO, whereas submissions to the Stacks project are reviewed by a human before they're incorporated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that [XyJax](http://sonoisa.github.io/xyjax/xyjax.html) is developed independently from [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). As a result, MathJax will not support nor test XyJax. This makes integration into MathOverflow difficult since we need to have reliable support for new features. We cannot implement such features without a suitable support plan from the XyJax developers.