# KaTeX vs MathJax

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, mathjax

According to some [benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/katex-vs-mathjax), it seems that [KaTeX](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX) renders latex much more faster than Mathjax.

Is there any chance to use KaTeX in place of Mathjax?

Comment: There has been some discussion at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16809/a-mathjax-alternative-from-khan-academy

Comment: There are some concerns, as highlighted in the answers given to the post that Gerry linked to. I'm going to let one of our developers answer this, please be patient :)

Comment: Although the functionality is currently limited, it seems to be worth keeping an eye on.

Comment: I marked this [meta-tag:status-deferred] for the two reasons I explained in my answer below. There seems to be no reasonable way to add KaTeX as a MathJax alternative on MO at this time. However, the issue could be revisited once KaTeX improves its functionality and starts offering support for their product.

Comment: See also the discussion with the same title on PhysicsOverflow: http://www.physicsoverflow.org/23869/katex-vs-mathjax?show=23970#c23970

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently, KaTeX supports a limited subset of the functionality provided by MathJax. Many of the missing functionality (notably arrays and equation alignment) is regularly used on MathOverflow, so I would not recommend using KaTeX for viewing MathOverflow.

http://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/wiki/Function-Support-in-KaTeX
http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#supported-latex-commands

A visual comparison can be found [here](http://www.intmath.com/cg5/katex-mathjax-comparison.php).

As noted [in an earlier discussion](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/989), there are also important security issues with adding third-party javascript on MathOverflow. As far as I can tell, the KaTeX developers are not yet offering adequate support for a large site with lots of user input like MathOverflow. They might eventually offer that since they obviously need to support the Khan Academy, which has similar security needs.