# Triangle commutative diagram does not work here at MO

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

I  frequently tried  to draw a triangle commutative  diagram similar to the  definition of projective  modules for this  question.

[A module associated to an endomorphism of a vector bundle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/320890/a-module-associated-to-an-endomorphism-of-a-vector-bundle)

so  I searched  in latex  stackexchange and  I  find  some  relevant post.

then  I copy  paste the  corresponding  commands and I observed that that does not work for  MO.

I  copied the  commands in this post:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/191462/creating-triangle-commutative-diagram-with-tikz-cd

(I prefer $\gamma$  lies  on a  Dots  arrows.

can I ask you to  kindly  help  me  to draw this  diagram.  such a diagram can present my  meaning  more precisely.

thank you in advance for your help.

P.S.:  Even when I try a  simple  command  as 
$$\begin{CD}
A \\
@VVV \\
B
\end{CD}$$

It  does not work  at  MO.

Comment: Maybe have a look at Mathematics Meta: [How to draw a commutative diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324) and [Challenge: can you draw the following triangular diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27590) Capabilities of MathJax in this direction are indeed limited, but if you want to use AMScd you need `\require{AMScd}`. See the post below.

Comment: You can find something related to commutative diagrams also in this previous post on this meta: [Is it possible to use tikzcd code in MO posts?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3792) Perhaps the chat conversation linked there might be useful too: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2018/7/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer made explicitly for testing.

```
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
A \\
@VVV \\
B
\end{CD}$$
```

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
A \\
@VVV \\
B
\end{CD}$$

```
$$\require{AMScd}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{
  \raise.6em\rlap{\scriptstyle #1}
  \lower.3em{\mathord{\diagup}}
  \raise.52em{\!\mathord{\nearrow}}
}}
\begin{CD}
&& E\\
& \diaguparrow{\gamma} @VV \alpha V \\
F @>> \beta> G
\end{CD}$$
```

$$\require{AMScd}
\def\diaguparrow#1{\smash{
  \raise.6em\rlap{\scriptstyle #1}
  \lower.3em{\mathord{\diagup}}
  \raise.52em{\!\mathord{\nearrow}}
}}
\begin{CD}
&& E\\
& \diaguparrow{\gamma} @VV \alpha V \\
F @>> \beta> G
\end{CD}$$
This comes from taking the three characters $\gamma \diagup \nearrow$, adjusting their heights, using *rlap* so that the first two characters overlap, using $\backslash !$ to back up the third character, using *smash* to make them all spill out of a $0\times 0$ box, and then putting that box in the right place.

Comment: Thank you very much for  your  answer. I  applied  your  help. But  can  you say  me  how can  I replace  the  inclined arrows by a  Doted one?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I do not know about a way to make the diagonal arrow dotted *using AMScd*. I have asked Davide Cervone (one of MathJax developers) [in the comments to his answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27590/challenge-can-you-draw-the-following-triangular-diagram/27594#comment126438_27594), he does not mention a way to do this either.

Answer (score 6):

**Added in 2022.** The website mentioned below does not work now - so this is no longer an option. (It seems that it has been down for some time. And the corresponding [GitHub repository](https://github.com/vpatryshev/presheaf) seems to be inactive, too. There are [only a few posts on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/search?tab=active&q=url%3a%22%2Apresheaf.com%2A%22) with such links. There are [more such posts](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22*presheaf.com*%22&pagesize=50) on Mathematics Stack Exchange.)

---

Especially for more complicated diagrams (where it's difficult to draw them using AMScd), a possible solution is to use [presheaf website](http://presheaf.com/) and include the picture into the post. I have learned about this site from Bruno Stonek's answer to [How to draw a commutative diagram?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2324#12372) (Mathematics Meta).

Advantages of this website:

- It is easy to use for people who are already familiar with xypic. (Of course there are also other [LaTeX packages for commutative diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/commutative-diagrams/info), the most popular probably are tikz-cd and xy-pic.)
- The code is compiled online and it generates picture which can be used elsewhere. (Naturally, some users might prefer to do this locally on their computer and convert the output from LaTeX to picture by themselves.)
- If you add link to the website, you simultaneously provide the xypic code.

I will explicitly mention that images uploaded through the editor should be stable and relatively immune to link rot, see: [Permanent Picture Uploads](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4205) (Mathematics Meta).

<sup>I am fully aware that this is not optimal from the viewpoint of [screen readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) and visually impaired users. However, web accessibility is probably quite a challenging issue when using commutative diagrams and various other visualizations.</sup>

Some examples:

http://presheaf.com/?d=d5f3h332d491j3m2v5j4g5o193hr503v

[image: {\hat P} \ar[rd]^k \ar[rrd]^{\hat f} \ar[rdd]{\hat g} \ & P \ar[r]{\overline f} \ar[d]^{\overline g} & B \ar[d]^g \ & A \ar[r]_f & C]

http://presheaf.com/?d=d564x6z6o2c383r6t3r55r375c4v4l1h

[image: & E \ar[d]\alpha \ E \ar@{..>}[ru]^\gamma \ar[r]\beta & E]

http://presheaf.com/?d=d4l86n4i40s4n18675m3rw6cye1p

[image: {X} \ar@{^{(}->}[r] \ar[rd]_f & {\beta X} \ar[d]^{\widehat f} \ & {K}]

http://presheaf.com/?d=d6213453at1p2gd324i21h3i4g3v32

[image: B \ar[r]^{r_B} \ar[rd]_{f}& {A_B} \ar@{-->}[d]^{\overline f} \ & A]

Comment: All the presheaf website links have gone stale.